# How to use ViewModel in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am very newbie to xamarin native for IOS. Can anyone show me a basic example for the mvvm pattern for iOS apps? How can we use a ViewModel?

Thank you.

Comment: Check https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/getting-started/getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An MVVM application has three layers:

- The Model provides underlying data, sometimes through files or web
  accesses
- The View is the user interface or presentation layer, generally
  implemented in XAML
- The ViewModel connects the Model and the View

Here are some official document about MVVM you can read:

[MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter18) and [the-mvvm-pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm#the-mvvm-pattern)

There are also examples and sample project there : [a-simple-viewmodel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm#a-simple-viewmodel)